# Was Mary inspired by Hannah?

Tags: luke, 1-samuel, inspiration

In 1 Samuel 2:1-10 (NASB)

> 1 Then Hannah prayed and said,
>
> “My heart rejoices in the Lord;
> My horn is exalted in the Lord,
>
> My mouth speaks boldly against my enemies,
>
> Because I rejoice in Your salvation.
>
> 2 There is no one holy like the Lord,
>
> Indeed, there is no one besides You,
>
> Nor is there any rock like our God.
>
> 3 Do not go on boasting so very proudly,
>
> Do not let arrogance come out of your mouth;
>
> For the Lord is a God of knowledge,
>
> And with Him actions are weighed.
>
> 4 The bows of the mighty are broken to pieces,
>
> But those who have stumbled strap on strength.
>
> 5 Those who were full hire themselves out for bread,
> But those who were hungry cease to be hungry.
>
> Even the infertile woman gives birth to seven,
>
> But she who has many children languishes.
>
> 6 The Lord puts to death and makes alive;
>
> He brings down to Sheol and brings up.
>
> 7 The Lord makes poor and rich;
> He humbles, He also exalts.
>
> 8 He raises the poor from the dust,
>
> He lifts the needy from the garbage heap
>
> To seat them with nobles,
> And He gives them a seat of honor as an inheritance;
>
> For the pillars of the earth are the Lord’s,
> And He set the world on them.
>
> 9 He watches over the feet of His godly ones,
> But the wicked ones are silenced in darkness;
> For not by might shall a person prevail.
>
> 10 Those who contend with the Lord will be terrified;
>
> Against them He will thunder in the heavens,
>
> The Lord will judge the ends of the earth;
>
> And He will give strength to His king,
>
> And will exalt the horn of His anointed.”

Then, in Luke 1:46-55 (NASB)

> 46 And Mary said:
>
> “My soul exalts the Lord,
>
> 47 And my spirit has rejoiced in God my Savior.
>
> 48 For He has had regard for the humble state of His bond-servant;
> For behold, from now on all generations will call me blessed.
>
> 49 For the Mighty One has done great things for me;
> And holy is His name.
>
> 50 And His mercy is to generation after generation
> Toward those who fear Him.
>
> 51 He has done mighty deeds with His arm;
>
> He has scattered those who were proud in the thoughts of their hearts.
>
> 52 He has brought down rulers from their thrones,
>
> And has exalted those who were humble.
>
> 53 He has filled the hungry with good things,
>
> And sent the rich away empty-handed.
>
> 54 He has given help to His servant Israel,
>
> In remembrance of His mercy,
>
> 55 Just as He spoke to our fathers,
>
> To Abraham and his descendants forever.”

Was Mary inspired by Hannah?

Comment: Mary, no doubt, was familiar with Hannah's exultant hymn of praise and thanksgiving and no doubt was influenced by that and other expressions in the psalms. But I am not clear as to your wording 'Luke being inspired in 1 Samuel'. These are _Mary's words_ being faithfully reported by Luke. Up-voted +1, nevertheless.

Comment: @NigelJ thank you for pointing that out. That observation could be result of my profession as software engineer. Edited the question to make it more human

Comment: Of course Mary's song alludes to Hannah's - why would it not?  This is not surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hannah and Mary had a lot in common.
When the songs were written, Hannah had given birth to Samuel while Mary was carrying Jesus in her womb.

Both songs open similarly with rejoicing:

Hannah opens with "**My heart rejoices in the Lord**. In the Lord my horn is lifted high. My mouth speaks boldly against my enemies,
Because **I rejoice in Your salvation**."

Mary opens with "My soul glorifies the Lord and **my spirit rejoices in God my Savior**."

The similarity between the two is remarkable.

Both saw themselves as lowly women that God lifted up. God's lifting up the humble people is a theme in both songs.

1 Samuel 2:7b-8

> He **humbles**, He also **exalts**.
> He raises the poor from the dust,
> He lifts the needy from the garbage heap.

Luke 1:52-53

> He has brought down rulers from their thrones,
> And has **exalted** those who were **humble**.
> He has filled the hungry with good things

Was Mary inspired by Hannah?

Definitely. Further, both were inspired by the Holy Spirit.